# Show that $\sqrt b \in \mathbb Q(\sqrt{a^2-b})$

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory

> Let $L$ be the splitting field of $f=X^4-2aX^2+b\in\mathbb Q[X]$.
>
> Show that $\sqrt b \in \mathbb Q(\sqrt{a^2-b})=:K$ if $[L:\mathbb Q]=4$.

EDIT: $a,b$ are chosen so that $f$ is irreducible.

Can I argue like this?
If we have $\sqrt b\notin K$, then $K(\sqrt b)$ is an extension of at least $2$ of $K$. On the other hand, since $f$ is irreducible we have that $\sqrt{a^2-b}\notin \mathbb Q$ and therefor $K/\mathbb Q$ is an extension of degree $2$. So, if $[L:K]=4$ we obtain $L=K(\sqrt b)=\mathbb Q(\sqrt b,\sqrt{a^2-b})$ by degree comparison. But then $L$ is the splitting field of $g=(X^2-b)(X^2-a^2+b)\neq f$ which is in conflict with the uniqueness of splitting fields.

Comment: Why should the polynomial be irreducible? For $a=b=1$ it is reducible. Also, $\sqrt{a^2-b}$ might be rational.

Comment: @egreg The assumption is $[L: \mathbb{Q}]$ =4.

Comment: Your proof is correct if you show that $\sqrt{b} \in L$.

Comment: Here is a counterexample: $f=X^4-5 X^2+6=\left(X^2-3\right) \left(X^2-2\right)$ and $[L:\mathbb{Q}]=4$, $\sqrt{a^2-b}$ is rational and $\sqrt{b}$ is not.

Comment: @PaulFrost I'm not saying that the polynomial *is* reducible; but since it *can* be, one has to use the hypothesis. However, it seems that one can't prove irreducibility.

Comment: I forgot to add that $f$ is irreducible by condition. @PaulFrost Okay, this follows easily by multiplying two roots of $f$.

Comment: The uniqueness argument does not work: Both $(X^2-2)(X^2-3)$ and $X^4 -10 X^2 + 1$ have the same splitting field $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt2, \sqrt3) = \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt2 + \sqrt3)$.

Comment: @egreg You are right!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $f$ is *irreducible* and $[L:\mathbb{Q}]=4$ then the Galois group has order four and acts transitively on the roots. In particular, the only element that fixes any root is the unit element. If $\alpha$ is a root then all roots are given by $\{\pm \alpha, \pm \beta\}$ where $\alpha \beta = \sqrt{b}$. Now $\alpha^2 - \beta^2 =\pm \sqrt{a^2 - b}$. The only non-trivial element that fixes $\alpha^2 - \beta^2$ sends $\alpha$ to $-\alpha$ and $\beta$ to $-\beta$ so in particular it fixes $\alpha \beta = \sqrt{b}$. Therefore $\sqrt{b} \in \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{a^2 - b})$.